# define narrow band and broadband in Infrared light source

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, spectroscopy, infrared-radiation

I have an infrared transmitter where the specification sheet says

> Broadband Emission from 400 to 2200 nm

Does this mean it will transmit all mixed wavelength of infrared light between 400 to 2200 nm? Also, what do narrow band and broadband mean with infrared light sources?

Comment: Hi Vignesh, I've made some grammatical & formatting corrections to your post, but I'm not certain of the intent of the last question. Can you ensure that I've correctly written what you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Broadband Emission from 400 to 2200 nm"...which means it will transmit all mixed wavelength of infrared light between 400 to 2200?

Yes, this is correct. But the light intensity will likely not be equal at all wavelengths, but will have some dependence, which may be in your spec sheet. Note that 400 - 700 nm is the visible range.

I don't know that there is an accepted definition of narrowband, because it depends on your application, but a reasonable definition would

$\frac{\Delta \lambda} {lambda} \ll 1$,

where $\Delta \lambda$ is the width of the spectrum.

The degree of "much less than" depends on the application. For instance, research-grade lasers used for precision spectroscopy would have widths something like $10^{-8} \lambda$.

Comment: thanks @Eoin, in my application i need to generate particular wavelength of IR and detect reflected IR, how do i generate particular wavelength and detect same reflected IR,.is there any instrument for that? how researchers find particular material absorb particular wavelength of IR

Comment: For detecting IR, you can use a photodiode. They're not (too) wavelength-sensitive, but that usually doesn't matter. If ypu're looking for something like ranging/object detection, I don't think you need a narrowband source, a wideband would work. If you really need a bit more specific wavelength, you could use an LED. Typical results from google tell me that they have a spectral width of maybe 40 nm near 880 nm. You may find similar things for your project.

Comment: Oh right.... You probably need a broadband source and a wavelength-sensitive detector -- a spectrometer. Search for "IR spectrometer" on google, and you find some projects people have done. You could make one "at home" with a diffraction grating and a CCD camera, or a Fabry-Perot cavity (more expensive), but it's going to have limited resolution to things you can buy. You can get proper setups to buy, but it's quite expensive.